# place an image exactly above the table with opacity

Tags: html, css

I want to place the attached image above the table with opacity. In my actual code the table is having clickable links, so to disable that i need to place this image above the table. Image should be across the table in a transparent container kind of.
Issue 1: Image is not placed above (across) the table, it is displaying below the table
Issue 2: Image should be in some div or kind of so that it is transparent that covers the whole table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width;400px;
}

.container img {vertical-align: middle;}

.container .content {
position:relative;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;  
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */  

font-size: 50px; 
text-align: center; 
font-style: italic; 
padding: 40px; 
padding-top: 180px; 
color: grey;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Image with Transparent Text</h2>

<div class="container"> 
<TABLE width="800px">
<TR>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
 <TD>Test</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
  <div class="content">    
    <IMG SRC="ComingSoon.png" WIDTH="548" HEIGHT="53" BORDER="0" ALT="">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image file for code snippet]

Comment: Is your goal to simply disable clicks?

Comment: Not only disable clicks, also i need to place that image across that table. Or a text similar to that image across that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, making links unclickable by placing a  picture over them is kind of a hacky solution, but who am I to judge? We all know there are sometimes situations, where a quick, hacky solution is more than enough... ;-)
So here you go:

### 1. Swap the `position` attributes of `.container` and `.container .content`.

(Make `.container` `relative` and `.container .content` `absolute`.)

Making `.container .content` `absolute` will position it over the table.

Technically, you could also leave `.container` `absolute`, but I'd recommend against that, because of the way positioning in CSS works: `absolute` is not necessarily the absolute position in the page, but in the next *positioned* ancestor, *positioned* meaning "having a `position` property". (If there is no positioned ancestor, then `body` is the reference.)
So it is important that `.container` is positioned, otherwise your image would also block the headline. To achieve that, it is enough, to give it a position property with any value. But `relative` is a safer value in this case, because it doesn't really affect the position of the element, unless you also give a `left`/`right`/`top` or `bottom` property. `absolute` on the other hand may under certain circumstances mess with your overall page layout.

### 2. Don't rotate `.container .content`, but `.container .content img` instead.

Rotating `.container .content` caused it to partially block the headline.

### 3. Remove `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` from `.container .content`.

While this step isn't really necessary to achieve what you want, those properties are obsolete. You either want to give the position of an element from the top OR the bottom, as well as from the left OR the right.
If you give both properties, browsers will just ignore one of them (probably the first one).

I hope my explanations were understandable... :-D

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

your positioning and CSS rules might be a bit off for what you're trying to achieve.

Your mixed a bit the css rules for the content div and the image inside. If you need to rotate the image, you should apply it only to the img tag and focus the padding and background color only on the div to cover the whole table without affecting the image bar. You keep both the content div and the img inside in position : absolute to let them cover the table and each other, then you can move them around friendly at your will (also make sure the div is as wide as the content you're trying to cover).

Here's my proposition, there might be some adjustments to be made on the image size and position but I think it's close to what you were describing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      max-width: 800px;
    }
    
    .container img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 25%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      /* Rotate div */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: rotate(-25deg);
    }
    
    .container .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      /* Fallback color */
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
      font-size: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font-style: italic;
      color: grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Responsive Image with Transparent Text</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <IMG SRC="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqmn.png" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="53" BORDER="0" ALT="">
    </div>
    <TABLE width="800px">
      <TR>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
        <TD>Test</TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.Looks like it is working. but need some alignment as you said.